Is it neccessary to do typedef in cpp when defining structs?
I was trying to learn C++, and stumbled upon the typedef. I have searched questions regarding, and they all say:
struct dummy {
   int x;
   int y;
};

typedef struct dummy dummy2;

is the same as
typedef struct dummy {
   int x;
   int y;
} dummy2;

which is fair, and most answers told me when I declare a new struct I will need to use the keyword struct if i use the orignal name.
but why do I need to do a typedef if I can do this without any warning or errors
#include <iostream>

struct pos{
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main(void){
    pos a = {1, 1};
    std::cout << a.x << " : " << a.y << "\n";
    return 0;
}


I know this is wrong becuase if I make a function with a similiar same it will cause an error. But what if don't make a function? Does it voilate some way of writing or standard? as I tried it with almost all warning flags and it did not give me any. Is it the compiler doing some things on its own?

and If I define the struct in different namespace in a header file without the typedef. What will be the syntax like to call that struct in the main file. What if I do include the typedef, do I need to give the alternate name a namespace:: heading?


I thought atleast a warning would be displayed regarding the missing struct keyword, but it did not.

"I know this is wrong becuase if I make a function with a similiar same it will cause an error" - That's not correct. You can have functions named like classes in the same scope with no error, it will then revert to the C behavior and require you to write struct pos.

The typedef is typical for C, where you have to use struct pos otherwise. In C++ pos is visible anyway. Only if you get a conflict with another item, like a pos function, do you have to use struct pos to differentiate.

why do I need to do a typedef I don't know why you need it, we don't need it.

So I should use the keyword struct if I use the original name regardless?

"So I should use the keyword struct if I use the original name regardless?" Only if you want your code to be C-compatible (i.e. in a header that you want to be able to #include into both C and C++ source files).  Otherwise it is unnecessary in C++.
